# Minimal modification of sequence that removes all local minima

Tags: algorithms

Consider a trail as a sequence of land heights representing the elevation along the trail. A pit is any position in the trail surrounded by higher terrain on both sides.
For example, in the sequence [1000, 600, 1700, 900, 900, 1400, 600], positions 1, 3 and 4 are all pits (elevations 600, 900 and 900 respectively).

We would like to fix the trail such that it includes no pits, but we wish to do it with the minimal amount of additional sand units. In the example above the solution would be: [1000, 1000, 1700, 1400, 1400, 1400, 600]. We added a total of 400+500+500=1400 sand units.

Assumptions:

- The sequence length $n$ may be large
- Terrain levels are always in the range $[0, k]$, where $k$ is much smaller than $n$.

> How do I solve this efficiently?

Comment: Java-specific questions are off-topic here, so I removed all references to Java.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this question? What is the best algorithm you can come up with?

Comment: Hints: suppose that position $i$ is a pit. How much sand would you need to add so that $i$ stops being a pit? Is it possible that filling $i$ using the chosen amount of sand creates some new pit? Is it possible that the act of filling $i$ also removes another pit $j \neq i$?

Comment: @Steven , Can you please give me a clearer hint, because I still don't know how to solve this efficently.

Comment: @arielb, did you figure out the answers to the questions in my hint?

Comment: @Steven, I didn't yet figure out the answer

Comment: Please credit the original source of all copied material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_i$ denote the $i$-th elevation and let $a^*_i$ the $i$-th elevation after the minimum amount of sand has been poured in order to remove all pits.

Let $p$ be a pit in the input instance.
The solution must pour at least $s^*_p = \min \{a_{p-1}, a_{p+1}\} - a_p$ units of sand in $p$. Indeed, if less than $s^*_p$ units of sand were poured we would have:
$$
a^*_p < a_p + s^*_p = \min \{a_{p-1}, a_{p+1}\} \le \min \{a^*_{p-1}, a^*_{p+1}\},
$$
showing that $a^*_p$ is a pit in the final configuration and yielding a contradiction.

Moreover, the solution that pours exactly $\min \{a_{p-1}, a_{p+1}\} - a_p$ units of sand in each pit $p$ of the input instance is feasible, and hence is optimal (since it matches the above lower bound).

To see that the solution is feasible, let $a'_i$ the final amount of sand in position $i$ and let $s_i = a'_i - a_i$.
Notice that if $i$ is an endpoint of the trail we have $s_i=0$. Otherwise  $s_i = \max \{ \min \{a_{i-1}, a_{i+1}\} - a_i, 0 \}$.

If $i$ is initially a pit, then $i-1$ and $i+1$ cannot be pits and hence $s_{i-1}=s_{i+1} = 0$. It follows that
$$a'_i = a_i + s_i =  \min \{a_{i-1}, a_{i+1}\} = \min \{a_{i-1} + s_{i-1}, a_{i+1}+s_{i+1}\} = \min \{a'_{i-1}, a'_{i+1}\},$$
showing that $i$ is no longer a pit in the final configuration.

If $i$ is not initially a pit, then $s_i=0$ and:
$$
a'_i = a_i + s_i = a_i = (a_i - a_{i+1}) + a_{i+1} \ge s_{i+1} + a_{i+1} = a'_{i+1},
$$
hence $i$ cannot become a pit in the final configuration.

Comment: is the time complexity of resolving all the pits O(N*N) ?

Comment: Yes and, in particular, it is $O(N)$.